# How to get unwrap value using combine framework

Tags: json, swift, combine

I am totally new at using the Combine framework.
The struct I am using:

```
enum AuthenticateResponse: Decodable, Hashable {
    struct Success: Decodable, Hashable {
        let url, id, firstName, lastName: String
        let email, phone: String
    }

    struct Failure: Decodable, Hashable {
        struct Errors: Decodable, Hashable {
            let code: [String]?
            let username: [String]?
            let password: [String]?
        }
        let message: String
        let errors: Errors
    }

    case success(Success)
    case failure(Failure)
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            let success = try Success(from: decoder)
            self = .success(success)
        } catch {
            let failure = try Failure(from: decoder)
            self = .failure(failure)
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this response from server:

```
failure(demo.AuthenticateResponse.Failure(
    message: "Invalid data..", 
    errors: demo.AuthenticateResponse.Failure.Errors(
        code: Optional(["The code does not exist."]), 
        username: nil, 
        password: nil)
    )
)
```

I am trying to get this value `code: Optional(["The code does not exist."]),` from above response using combine but I couldn’t

I am using below code to get that value:

```
func syncOnlineData() {
    print("I am here")
    viewModel.authenticateResponse
        .sink { result in
            print("result: \(result)")
        } receiveValue: { res in
            print("value: \(String(describing: res))")
        }
}
```

main response from server:

```
["errors": {
    code =     (
        "The code does not exist."
    );
}, "message": Invalid data.]
```

How I will get the value from `code` ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Combine? What I mean is: how would you get that value from the server response, if you had never heard of Combine? When you show that, it will be easy to translate it into Combine.

Comment: Also, your code does not actually seem to use Combine. Combine is not something you call. You create a pipeline, store it, and get out of the way, waiting for the publisher to publish. Where is your publisher? Where is your storage? What is `viewModel.authenticateResponse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is the AuthenticateResponse right?

If that's the case

```
.sink { result in 
    guard case .failure(let failure) = result else { return }

    // here is the code for each error
    print("do something for code: \(failure.errors.code)")
}
```

Comment: errors is not an array

Comment: @LeoDabus yeah it's an arrary.

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan In your declaration `Errors` is a struct which contains 3 collections(`code`, `username`, and `password`) but it is not an array. You can not iterate `errors`.

Comment: @LeoDabus Good eye. Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

`Biclops` thanks for your help and giving me the light. If someone structure like above one this kinda best way to get your value:

```
.sink { result in
    switch result {
    case .none:
        print("--")
    case .some(let jsonValue):
        switch jsonValue {
        case .success(let success):
            self.verificationMessageLabel.isHidden = true
            self.continueButton.isEnabled = true
            print("success: \(success)")
        case .failure(let fail):
            guard let errorMsg = fail.errors.code else { return }
            errorMsg.forEach { errString in
                print(errString)
            }

        }
    }
}
```